# Effect of Parentheses in a LINQ Extension Method Query

Tags: linq, syntax, extension-methods

Is there any difference if I leave the parentheses around `queryable` and `OrderByDescending(...)` (and before `Take(1)`) or remove them? Why or why not?

```
public static IQueryable<IEffectiveDated> GetCurrent(this IQueryable<IEffectiveDated> queryable, DateTime asOfDate) 
{           
    return (queryable
        .Where(e => e.EffectiveDate <= asOfDate)
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.EffectiveDate))
        .Take(1);       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference in this case. In other words:

```
return (queryable
    .Where(e => e.EffectiveDate <= asOfDate)
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.EffectiveDate))
    .Take(1);
```

is identical to:

```
return queryable
    .Where(e => e.EffectiveDate <= asOfDate)
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.EffectiveDate)
    .Take(1);
```

The later is probably cleaner and better shows the Linq chaining.